# Apply filter to HTML5 video without CSS

Tags: javascript, html, video, getusermedia

I'm looking for a way to apply some filters to a video (took from webcamera in real time), but without using any kind of CSS class.

**I do not want** to create a CSS class like:

```
.blur {
   -webkit-filter: blur(1px);
   -moz-filter: blur(1px);
   -o-filter: blur(1px);
   -ms-filter: blur(1px);
   filter: blur(1px);
}
```

And apply it like `document.getElementById("myvideo").className = "blur"`. No, **I'm not looking for this. I need to embed this filter into video so users can quit them.** (using injected CSS is not an option).

To clearify myself: I'm not looking for solutions like this http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/css/filters/index.html

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks

EDIT:

I have code like I post before, where I have a CSS class that I assign to my canvas to apply  a filter whenever I want

Problem? Users can disable injected CSS using Developer Tools included in Chrome, or using Firebug (by disabling classes, or elements individually).

So I need a solution to apply filters like these, but without injecting CSS into my `canvas` element.

Comment: could you explain a little more about what you mean by "embed this filter into video so users can quit them"?

Comment: you can do stuff like that in a <canvas>, but it's going to be a CPU hog...

Comment: I edited my own post. (Downvoted? really? why?)

Comment: You want a client-side solution that the user can't turn off, ever? That seems unlikely. (Also, why do you need to prevent users from doing that in the first place? So what if they can turn off blurring using some tool?)

Comment: @Dpeif — I think he means "can't".

Comment: @Pekka웃 It's streaming from webcamer, not a video previously recorded. I want to apply filters to that stream.

Comment: Is this to blur... delicate body parts? :) (Edit: ah, probably not, looking at your web site.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to apply your filters to the video data before delivering it to the browser. There are lots of ways you could do this, for example: ffmpeg supports [various filters](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/FilteringGuide) (including blur).

Anything you can do on the client can be undone by the user (the user controls the client, you don't).

Comment: My idea is to apply it to webcamera streaming in real time. Can I do this using HTML5 video streaming?

Comment: @Fran not likely. If you want to apply an effect that the client can't remove under any circumstances,  you'll need to do it on server side. No idea what kind of streaming software supports real-time effects but I'm sure they are out there (although possibly not free)

Comment: @Pekka웃 It's an augmented reality package using HTML5 video streaming, so I'm unable to use any software for streaming :( (love free, all body parts can be seen :D)

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Seriously.js](http://github.com/brianchirls/Seriously.js) for a huge pile of filters that can target a canvas, video, img or other html element!

Comment: http://seriouslyjs.org/ is broken, you're probably referring to https://github.com/brianchirls/Seriously.js/

Comment: Thank you, appears the demo site did die. I updated my original response to point directly to it's github.

Answer (score 0):

If you like to apply filter to a video stream from getUserMedia, you can show the video in a `<Canvas>` instead of `<Video>`.

I understand that this is not a very good solution though since it will eat alot of CPU. But you will have few limitations in what filters you can apply.

Comment: I'm currently showing video in a `Canvas` instead of `Video` and I'm trying to apply video on this canvas, but I do not want it like injected CSS.